# c# Selection Sort Is Setting Weight of One Object To Another Instead of Sorting Ascending Min To High

Tags: c#, sorting, properties, console, selection

This is homework.  My goal is to create a selection sort that sorts my animals in my zoo by ascending the animals weight low to high given their weight.  I wouldn't be being honest if I said I struggle with the logic for the selection sort as my code shows.

```
 public static SortResult SelectionSortByWeight(List<Animal> animals)
    {
        // initialize a swap counter variable
        int swapCounter = 0;
        SortResult result = new SortResult();

        // loop forward through the list
        for (int i = 0; i < animals.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            // declare a variable to hold the animal with the current minimum weight
            Animal a = animals[i];
            // set the variable to the current animal
            a = animals[i];

            // loop through the remaining animals in the list to find the animal with the lowest weight
            for (int j = i + 1; j < animals.Count; j++)
            {
                // if the weight of the current animal is less than the weight of the animal with the minimum weight,
                if(animals[i].Weight < animals[j].Weight)

                // set the variable holding the animal with the current minimum weight to the current animal
                {
                    animals[i].Weight = animals[j].Weight;
                }

                // after finding the animal with the lowest weight
                // if the current animal's weight does not equal the weight of the animal with current minimum weight, swap the two animals and increment the swap count
                if (animals[i].Weight != animals[j].Weight)
                {
                    Swap(animals, j, i);
                    swapCounter++;
                }
            }
        }

        result.Animals = animals;
        result.SwapCount = swapCounter;
        return result;
    }
```

My result that appears to work correctly until I reach my dingo's is:

[image]

Guidance in the correct direction is appreciated.

Comment: `if (animals[i].Weight < animals[j].Weight) animals[i].Weight = animals[j].Weight;` This logic seems problematic. You're assigning the weight of one (heavier) animal to another (lighter) animal. Probably why most of them end up with `810.6` as a weight.

Comment: Also a side note: `a = animals[i];` <= this line is redundant since the assignment was already done in the previous line. Also it's curious that you store the current animal in `a`, yet you never actually reference `a` anywhere - the code continues to use `animals[i]`, so it seems that the creation of `a` could be removed altogether.

Comment: The swapping is always : temp = a; a = b; b = temp; You cannot swap in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main problems here is that you're assigning the weight of one animal to another when you do this: `if (animals[i].Weight < animals[j].Weight) animals[i].Weight = animals[j].Weight;`. This is why most of the items at the end have the same weight.

Logically speaking, what you likely want to do is store the **index** of the animal with the lowest weight for the current subset (and by subset I mean the portion of the array that begins with `i`).

We would start out with the first line in the outer loop storing `i` as the lightest animal, something like: `int minIndex = i;`. Then we use our inner loop to check the rest of the animals. If at any point we have `animals[j].Weight < animals[minIndex].Weight`, then we know we've found a lighter animal, and we should now store *that* index, like: `minIndex = j;`

After the inner loop is done (but still inside the outer loop), we know that `minIndex` represents the location of the lightest animal in the subset that begins with `i`. If this index is different than `i`, then we `Swap(animals, i, minIndex)`.

After the outer loop completes, we should have a selection-sorted array.